# Mysql not connecting when callng from proc_open in php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, shell

There is a Linux shell script which includes mysql connection and queries.
filename is backup.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

user="root"
pass="dbpass"

output=`/usr/local/mariadb/bin/mysql -u$user -p$pass -h127.0.0.1 -e 'select now()' `
echo "data output=$output"
```

It will work if i run thorugh below linux command line.

```
sh backup.sh
```

But if i call from php code it will not work. It throughs **permission denied** error.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
                0 => array("pipe", "r"),
                1 => array("pipe", "w"),
                2 => array("pipe", "r")
        );

 $process = proc_open("sh /tmp/backup.sh", $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null);          if (is_resource($process))
        {
                //echo ("<br>Start process:<br>");


                stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], 0);

                while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
                        $out = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
                        echo ''.$out.'';
                }

    }
```

Anybody help me pls.

Comment: this is an incredibly bad way of doing this. Why not just use the mysqli or pdo api built into php??

Comment: we will include some additional functionality in this shell script.

Comment: Is the "permission denied" error coming from MySQL PHP or sh?

Comment: What ever that additional functionality is PHP gives you far better tools than bash to build it with.

Comment: error coming from Mysql PHP

Comment: PHP error code is 126